# Как укоротить сообщения об ошибках и предупреждения компилятора?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

Как укоротить сообщения об ошибках и предупреждения компилятора? Особенно при ошибках в шаблонах сначала идёт куча строк, в каком файле инстанциация поломалась, а только потом строка, в которой проблема, поэтому приходится проматывать в IDE. Файлы стандартной библиотеки меня не интересуют, только файлы проекта.

В частности, интересуют gcc и clang.

Comment: Флаг `-Wfatal-errors` может помочь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда то у меня такое же было желание. Самое большее раздражало, что std::string разворачивался в большущую портянку. Поэтому, я взял известный скрипт [colorgcc](https://github.com/colorgcc/colorgcc/blob/master/colorgcc.pl) и дописал туда замену. Вывод стал заметно меньше и красивее. Также у этого скрипта описано, как его правильно подключить, что бы все хорошо работало. А вот что именно нужно вырезать - это уже Вам виднее. Но возможно нужно не искать строки, которые вырезать, а искать строки, которые нужно оставить.